# Switch GPU in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS from AMD to Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, nvidia-prime

I am a new Ubuntu user and I have bougth a new laptop wich include a GTX 1650 GPU but Ubuntu is using the CPU integrated GPU. I would like to switch to the 1650 but I did not manage to do it...
I have first tried to install the drivers for the 1650 but it says the Prime is not supported when I try to launch

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

I have tried this :

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

and it tells me that prime is already installed...

I have looked for a workaround but nothing worked.
Any suggestions please ?

new OUTPUT for `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`
is

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 86d5
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 86d5
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` :

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-37-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

output for `prime-select query` is :

```
nvidia
```

IMPORTANT EDIT !
I have purger the drivers and install them back with the ubuntu additional drivers panel (the nvidia 440 drivers) I have also install prime and know it says that there is an error.
Here is the output for `nvidia-settings`

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:2747): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:35:48.650: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 15:35:48.657: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 15:35:48.657: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101958/discussion-on-question-by-lefantom55-switch-gpu-in-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-from-amd-t).

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem like a simple answer, but it doesn't look like you have tried switching to the driver in the default way that Ubuntu provides to you:

the `additional drivers` tab in the software & updates program. Go there and see if you're able to switch to it.

also, if you'd like to install the latest 440 driver for an Nvidia GPU, here is the PPA for it:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`

then do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -yy`

be careful when using random peoples commands that involve the sudo call.

Comment: I am already on the Nvidia drivers trough this window (Ubuntu additional drivers tab)